# Creting UDF function with NonPrimitive Data Type and using in Spark-sql Query: Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am creating one function in scala which i want to use in my spark-sql query.my query is working fine in hive or if i am giving the same query in spark sql but the same query i'm using at multiple places so i want to create it as reusable function/method so whenever its required i can just call it.
I have created below function in my scala class.

```
def date_part(date_column:Column) = {
    val m1: Column = month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_column, "dd-MM-yyyy")))) //give  value as 01,02...etc

    m1 match {
        case 01 => concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_column, "dd-MM- yyyy"))))-1,'-'),substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_column, "dd-MM-yyyy")))),3,4))
        //etc..
        case _ => "some other logic"
    }
}
```

but its showing multiple error.

1. For 01:

> ◾Decimal integer literals may not have a leading zero. (Octal syntax
>   is obsolete.)
>
> ◾type mismatch; found : Int(0) required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column.

2. For '-':

> type mismatch; found : Char('-') required:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column.

3. For 'substr':

> not found: value substr.

also that if I'm creating any simple function also with type as column I'm not able to register it as I'm getting error not possible in columnar format.and for all primitive data types(String,Long,Int) its working fine.But in my case type is column so 
I'm not able to do this.Can someone please guide me how should i do this.as of now I found on stack-overflow that i need use this function with df and then need to convert this df as temp table.can someone please guide me any other alternate way so without much changes in my existing code i can use this functionality.

Comment: Can you give me details like what is your input and output u want ??

Comment: Input-->date_column--->i.e. 03-01-2019 first I want to fetch month part and assigning into m1  i.e.01..if month  01 then checking through case statement and want output as 012019(mmyyyy) etc..@Srinivas

Comment: I have added answer below check that & let me know if its not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code.

```
scala> import org.joda.time.format._
import org.joda.time.format._

scala> spark.udf.register("datePart",(date:String) => DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy").parseDateTime(date).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMyyyy")))
res102: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> spark.sql("""select datePart("03-01-2019") as datepart""").show
+--------+
|datepart|
+--------+
|  032019|
+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Srinivas it worked for me.Just have one more doubt when i am writing this code in seprate scala object as 

object UDF_Class {
def MMyyyy_Date(args: Array[String]) = {
    spark.udf.register("datePart",(date:String) => DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy").parseDateTime(date).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMyyyy")))
}
}and then calling in another class as
 import pkg_name.UDF_Class.MMyyyy_Date
 and then using it in sparksql query as 
 spark.sql("select datePar(columnname) as dpart from dbname.tablename")

Comment: its showing not a registerd function do i need to add some more things(import..) in my 2nd calss where i want to use this.

Comment: you have to register udf where u want to use or keep in package object and import that package it will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Spark will need read a file where data is stored, I guess this file is a CSV but you can use method json insted of csv.

Then you can add new columns with a calculated value as follow:

```
     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

      val df = spark.read
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .csv("/path/mydata.csv")

      def transformDate( dateColumn: String, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
         df.withColumn("calculatedCol", month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(dateColumn), "dd-MM-yyyy")))))

         df.withColumn("newColumnWithDate",  when(col("calculatedCol") === "01", concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM- yyyy"))))-1, lit('-')),substring(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol")), "dd-MM-yyyy"))),4,2))
          .when(col("calculatedCol") === "02","some other logic")
          .otherwise("nothing match")))
      }

     // calling your function for the Dataframe you want transform date column:
     transformDate("date_column", df)
```

Note some functions need a column as argument, not a string value, so use lit() for specify that values.

An UDF is not needed (and in terms of performance is not recommendable) but you can use it in the following way:

```
val upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val upperUDF = udf(upper)
df.withColumn("upper", upperUDF('text)).show
```

Where 'upper' function will be the method you must include the logic to transform date column.

Comment: but in that case its not reusable right?Everywhere i need to write this much code i want to use it as a reusable function so i can call it whereever required @mrElefant

Comment: Yes, it is, I will edit my answer to describe a reusable function... let me 5 min

Comment: Just it, let me know if it is enough

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrElephant and Srinivas Your answer helped me alot.However I'm still facing some issues while Implementing 2nd UDF which mentioned by  MrElephant. I have posted that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662077/creating-and-using-spark-hive-udf-for-date  since i had to paste code and in comment section i was not able to paste complete code.