# Creating and using Spark-Hive UDF for Date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Note: this question is linked from this question: [Creting UDF function with NonPrimitive Data Type and using in Spark-sql Query: Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650367/creting-udf-function-with-nonprimitive-data-type-and-using-in-spark-sql-query-s)

I have created a method in scala:

```
    package test.udf.demo
    object UDF_Class {
    def transformDate( dateColumn: String, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    val sparksession = SparkSession.builder().appName("App").getOrCreate()
    val d=df.withColumn("calculatedCol", month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(dateColumn),  "dd-MM-yyyy")))))
    df.withColumn("date1",  when(col("calculatedCol") === "01",  concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM- yyyy"))))-1,  lit('-')),substring(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol")), "dd-MM- yyyy"))),3,4))
    .when(col("calculatedCol") ===  "02",concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM- yyyy"))))-1,  lit('-')),substring(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol")), "dd-MM- yyyy"))),3,4)))
    .when(col("calculatedCol") ===  "03",concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM- yyyy"))))-1,  lit('-')),substring(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol")), "dd-MM-yyyy"))),3,4)))
    .otherwise(concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM-  yyyy")))), lit('-')), substring(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("calculatedCol"), "dd-MM-yyyy")))) + 1, 3, 4))))) 
    val d1=sparksession.udf.register("transform",transformDate _)
    d
    }
    }
```

I want to use this transformDate method in my sparksql query which is separate scala code in same package.

```
    package test.udf.demo
    import test.udf.demo.transformDate
    //sparksession
    sparksession.sql("select id,name,salary,transform(dob) from dbname.tablename")
```

but I get an error

> not a temp or permanent registered function in default database

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Spark user defined udfs can cannot accept or return `DataFrame`. That is stopping your udf from registration

Answer (score 0):

First of all Spark SQL UDF is a Row based function. Not a Dataframe based method. Aggregate UDF also takes a series of Row. So the UDF definition is wrong. If I understood your requirement correctly you want to create a configurable expression of Case statements. It can be easily achieved by expr()

```
import spark.implicits._
val exprStr = "case when calculatedCol='01' then <here goes your code statements> as FP"
val modifiedDf = sql("""select id,name,salary,$exprStr  from dbname.tablename""")
```

It will work

Comment: Yes i want to Implement case stament with multiple conditions......but in this case its not reusable right?I want to use it in  different different scala codes.thats by  wanted to create as a UDF,so wherever  its required i can just call it.and can accordingly pass column name as argument.@Subhasish Guha

Comment: So then create a method where these column names of the case are coming from some input. It solves your generic case problem then